# Popup panel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make the opening panel as shown in the picture. But the problem is that this panel is positioned absolutely and when you move the window the panel stands in one position.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1vVX.png)

Here is my code on this issue:

XAML(MainWindow)

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions Height="50">
   <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Button x:Name="dotsBtn" Content="●●●" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#767779" Click="dotsBtn_Click" />
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource popupStyle}" Content="{Binding}"/>
<Popup x:Name="popup_uc" PopupAnimation="Fade" AllowsTransparency="True">
   <local:PopUpSort />
</Popup>
<Grid>
```

XAML(User control WPF)

```
...
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Border CornerRadius="10"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="0" Direction="100" BlurRadius="26" Opacity="0.15"/>
            </Border.Effect>
            <Grid>
                <Border Name="mask" Background="White" CornerRadius="20"/>
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=mask}"/>
                    </StackPanel.OpacityMask>
                    <Grid Width="300">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Content="Popular" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="#333333" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="70"/>
                        <Button Content="Cheap" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="#333333" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="70" />
                        <Button Content="Expensive" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="#333333" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="70" />
                        <Button Content="New" Grid.Row="3" Foreground="#333333" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="70" BorderBrush="Transparent" />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

.cs code (MainWindow)

```
...
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dotsBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if(popup_uc.IsOpen != true)
            {
                popup_uc.PlacementTarget = dotsBtn;
                popup_uc.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
                popup_uc.IsOpen = true;
            }
            else
                popup_uc.IsOpen = false;
        }

        private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            popup_uc.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }
...
```

The code works, but again with respect to the entire computer screen, that is, absolutely.

Here is the result:

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SfMT.png)

Comment: Normally when some initial position is set, a non-modal popup window will not move along with the caller window. You will have to implement that in a mouse move event. You align the left above of the popup with your [...] button, which seems to work, when I look at your picture. For various other settings for PlacementMode, check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.placementmode?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I don’t understand why I need an event handler for mouse movement? Could you specifically show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Window.LocationChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.locationchanged?view=netframework-4.8). Here's an example:

```
// If the eventhandler is created using Properties window:
private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(popup_uc.IsOpen)
    {
        popup_uc.PlacementTarget = dotsBtn;
        popup_uc.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this does nothing, when you drag the window, the position of the panel remains in place.

Comment: Tip: insert Debug.WriteLine("Event") in your event handler and move your window, to check if your eventhandler is actually connected..

Comment: I did so from the very beginning, it assigns a value but the panel does not change the position

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design. `Popup` is an independent window. It's children are not part of the visual tree. You either have to implement your own context menu like dropdown e.g. by toggling the `Visibility` of a `Grid`, which would be part of the visual tree and therefore automatically move when its parent is moving.

Alternatively implement an attached behavior that tracks the location and size of the `Popup.PlacementTarget` parent `Window`:

**Usage**

```
<StackPanel>
  <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton" Content="***" />
  <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ExpanderButton}" 
         Popup.IsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabled="True"
         IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=ExpanderButton, Path=IsChecked}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**Popup.cs**

```
class Popup : DependencyObject
{
  #region IsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabled attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabledProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "IsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabled",
      typeof(bool),
      typeof(Popup),
      new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), Popup.OnIsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabledChanged));

  public static void SetIsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement, bool value) =>
    attachingElement.SetValue(Popup.IsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabledProperty, value);

  public static bool GetIsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabled(DependencyObject attachingElement) =>
    (bool) attachingElement.GetValue(Popup.IsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabledProperty);

  #endregion

  private static Dictionary<Window, IList<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup>> WindowToPopupsMap { get; set; }

  static Popup() => Popup.WindowToPopupsMap = new Dictionary<Window, IList<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup>>();


  private static void OnIsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabledChanged(
    DependencyObject attachingElement,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!(attachingElement is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup))
    {
      throw new ArgumentException("Attaching element must be of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup'");
    }

    bool isEnabled = (bool) e.NewValue;

    if (isEnabled)
    {
      if (!popup.IsLoaded)
      {
        popup.Loaded += EnableFollowTargetMovementOnPopupLoaded;
        return;
      }

      Popup.EnableFollowTargetMovement(popup);
    }
    else
    {
      Popup.DisableFollowTargetMovement(popup);
    }
  }

  private static void EnableFollowTargetMovementOnPopupLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    Popup.EnableFollowTargetMovement(sender as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup);
  }

  private static void EnableFollowTargetMovement(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup)
  {
    Window window = Popup.GetParentWindow(popup);
    if (Popup.WindowToPopupsMap.TryGetValue(window, out IList<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup> popups)
        && !popups.Contains(popup))
    {
      popups.Add(popup);
    }
    else
    {
      Popup.WindowToPopupsMap.Add(window, new List<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup>() {popup});
    }

    WeakEventManager<Window, EventArgs>.AddHandler(
      window,
      nameof(Window.LocationChanged),
      Popup.UpdatePopup_OnParentWindowMoved);

    WeakEventManager<Window, SizeChangedEventArgs>.AddHandler(
      window,
      nameof(FrameworkElement.SizeChanged),
      Popup.UpdatePopup_OnParentWindowSizeChanged);
  }

  private static void DisableFollowTargetMovement(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup)
  {
    Window window = Popup.GetParentWindow(popup);
    if (Popup.WindowToPopupsMap.TryGetValue(window, out IList<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup> popups)
        && !popups.Contains(popup))
    {
      popups.Remove(popup);
      if (!popups.Any())
      {
        Popup.WindowToPopupsMap.Remove(window);
      }
    }

    WeakEventManager<Window, EventArgs>.RemoveHandler(
      window,
      nameof(Window.LocationChanged),
      Popup.UpdatePopup_OnParentWindowMoved);

    WeakEventManager<Window, SizeChangedEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(
      window,
      nameof(FrameworkElement.SizeChanged),
      Popup.UpdatePopup_OnParentWindowSizeChanged);
  }

  private static Window GetParentWindow(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup)
  {
    if (popup.PlacementTarget == null || !Popup.TryFindVisualParentElement(popup.PlacementTarget, out Window window))
    {
      window = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    }

    return window;
  }

  private static void UpdatePopup_OnParentWindowMoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var window = sender as Window;
    Popup.UpdatePopupPosition(window);
  }

  private static void UpdatePopup_OnParentWindowSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var window = sender as Window;
    Popup.UpdatePopupPosition(window);
  }

  private static void UpdatePopupPosition(Window window)
  {
    if (Popup.WindowToPopupsMap.TryGetValue(window, out IList<System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup> popups))
    {
      foreach (var popup in popups)
      {
        popup.HorizontalOffset += 1;
        popup.HorizontalOffset -= 1;
      }
    }
  }

  public static bool TryFindVisualParentElement<TParent>(DependencyObject child, out TParent resultElement)
    where TParent : DependencyObject
  {
    resultElement = null;

    DependencyObject parentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    if (parentElement is TParent parent)
    {
      resultElement = parent;
      return true;
    }

    return TryFindVisualParentElement(parentElement, out resultElement);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have an error Attaching element must be of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup'

Comment: You have to use the WPF `Popup` control. I've tested the code and it works. Please check if you are using the right control.

Comment: I have updated the code. The current version now also reposition the `Popup`, when the `PlacementTarget` parent `Window` was resized.

Comment: I created a clean wpf project to test your code, then I pasted your xaml code in my MainWindow.xaml between the Grid, then I created a new .cs file and named it popup.cs and pasted your .cs code there. As a result, 2 errors:
The attachable property 'IsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabled' was not found in type 'Popup'.
And error number two: The attachable property 'IsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabled' was not found in type 'Popup'.

Comment: I decided to add **local:** to **IsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabled** to the popup control, so that it turns out: local: Popup.IsFollowPlacementTargetPositionEnabled = "True".
One error is gone, but the second is left; this is error number two. The code starts, but the button does nothing.

Comment: You have just added the namespace, that's correct. I left the namespace because it depends on the current class or project structure. Usually VS will assist you and provide a fix for this error. Generally you will have to fully qualify every class except the default framework classes. Regarding the button, can you please check that you don't have typos? ToggleButton name must match the Binding.ElementName. Also verify that your bindings and everything matches the example. If this doesn't help start your application in debug mode and check for exceptions. Also check the Output Window.

Comment: But what are you doing!? Are you trying to apply a `Style` to the `Popup`? Why? Never do this in C#. Always use XAML. Test it without a `Style` first. If you still can't make it work, please edit your question and post your current code. Maybe we can fix it together. Let me know about your results.

Comment: Maybe you send me your project using dropmefiles.com?